# SocketException (The system call was cancelled) 

Tags: android, sockets, udp

I am working on a android project and I need to connect the gPhone with the PC using UDP socket. The same operation, sending a message to from gPhone to the PC, returns different results in different time: Sometimes succeeded and sometimes throws a `SocketException`(The system call was cancelled).

Can anyone tell me what possibly results in this `SocketException`?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your app's manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I have added this to the manifest before asking this question. Since the sending operation succeeds sometimes (and fails sometimes), I believe the problem is not the internet permission.
Thanks! :)